# How to call Spring MVC controller within Framework?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jms, spring-jms

In my Spring project, I do have a JMS message listener, managed by spring:

```
<bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"/>

<bean id="simpleExampleListener" class="my.package.ExampleListener" />

<jms:listener-container container-type="default" connection-factory="jmsFactory" acknowledge="auto" concurrency="1-3">
    <jms:listener destination="TEST.FOO" ref="simpleExampleListener" method="onMessage"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

On one particular message, I need to call a Spring MVC controller, which is request-scoped (actually goal is to call a service, which is also request-scoped and being called by a Controller). So I cannot do it directly from the listener, as Spring is managing them as needed and they are not request scope bound (because of that I cannot access the Controller via `@Autowire` or `ApplicationContext`). One of solutions could be a HTTP call with Rest Template to URL, mapped by my controller. But, I think, its kind of overhead, so maybe there is some other way to avoid HTTP protocol overhead and make a call to Controller within the Spring MVC framework?

Comment: Could you use prototype scope, rather than request scope?

Comment: if you did make the Http call at least that would be loosely coupled to the webapp code. calling the controller directly is much uglier.

Comment: Can you explain **why** do you want to call a controller from message listener? I can't think of any use case...

Comment: @Nathan Hughes: well actually, goal is to call service (also request-scoped), which is called by controller, so controller could be skipped and service called directly, which would not make it ugly anymore...

Comment: agreed. so call the service, problem solved ^_^

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz: my bad, as already answered to Nathan Hughes, my goal is to call a request-scoped service, which can be called two ways: via controller - as normal request or when there is a message from in a message Queue (the 2nd part I am trying to achieve now).

Comment: @Nathan Hughes: problem would be solved if I would call it, but now it has `@Scope("request")`, so I cannot access it from my Listener... :)

Comment: ick. i'd assumed the service would have singleton scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to question why the service class is defined as request-scope - ideally the service layer should not have any implicit / explicit dependency on the web layer.  If that is not in your control you can use the following work around. You will need to add spring-test.jar as a dependency.

```
    class Listener {

    @Autowired
    RequestScopedService requestScopedService;


    void handle() {
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));
        try {
             requestScopedService.callSomeMethod();
        } finally {
             ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).requestCompleted();
             RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
        }
```

If the service bean is configured with `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` tag then it can be autowired. Otherwise you need to get the application context (by implementing ApplicationContextAware) and doing a lookup.